# Collecting money without providing service is SCAM. Does your service work?

Tags: mapbox, openmaptiles

Two days ago I've purchased custom map extraction but still can't get it. On my account, I can only see status "waiting".

I've written you on info@klokantech.com, but nobody answered me.

**Collecting money without providing service is SCAM**

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't customer service

Comment: Oh, really? I've paid money, they haven't provided service and don't answer email. Where should I write about this?

Comment: Yes, [really](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/3001761).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The OpenMapTiles extract which was ordered has been delivered (on Saturday).**

We apologize for the delay in processing of your extract. The servers were busy with orders from other customers - and your job was scheduled and waiting in an automated processing queue (as the website communicated).

We are working on speeding up the extract service - and also constantly improving the communication processes on our side. During the holiday season, our reaction time on email may be slightly longer, unfortunately. These complaints were published on weekend in our time zone. Anyway, I hope the case is resolved.

Thank you for your feedback and loyalty!

This request has been answered at info@klokantech.com (where it belongs).

Similar non-technical requests DO NOT BELONG to StackOverflow or GitHub!